# Growing peaches from (supermarket) bought seeds

Tags: trees

As a hobby I like to grow stuff from the seeds of fruits (or bascially everything) that I buy in grocery stores.

I have heared often that if the trees will eventually grow own fruits, they will not taste well, or maybe they do not even grow fruits.

What is the reason for this?
I know that normally the trees are 'grafted', but I do not see the reason why this causes bad taste by seed grown trees.

Can you explain?

Comment: Not sure about peaches but in apples the part you eat is made from the genes of the only the mother plant, but apples breed easier with very different strains of apples, and breeding is required to make fruit , so the fruit body  may be say honeycrisp but the seeds will be a hybrid of honeycrips and crab apple.

Comment: Having done this for peaches, the fruit was not as large it still good. This is usual.

Comment: @John Thank you for this comment. I didnt know this. Very interesting.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll admit I'm not super familiar with peaches specifically, but many agricultural strains are carefully selected [hybrids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_seed) of true-breeding plants.

That means that you take two breeding stocks that are crossed with themselves extensively to the point that we can consider them [homozygous at all alleles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-breeding_organism), and then you breed two of those plants together. The resulting [F1 generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_hybrid) is your primary agricultural production strain.

You can get more seeds by continuing to successively inbreed and cross-breed the parental strains, or by making grafts (clones) of the hybrid strain. Importantly, the F1 generation of two inbred strains will be genetically consistent.

Not every F1 generation is going to be the perfect plant, but if you carefully test and try out different parent strains, you can find combinations that give you a great offspring.

If you breed the F1 generation, you don't get a constant offspring but rather a whole mix of possible phenotypes. Some might be great, some not, but they're going to be much more unreliable.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seedless_fruit

Comment: Very insightful. Thank you.